# Format title: section number flush left and title centered?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, titlesec

How can I format with the ***titlesec***  package that I get somethine like this (this is a twocolumn document):

[image]

I do not know how to get the number to the left and the title in the center is this possible?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: changed title to indicate that section number is flush left; ragged left means flush right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put the title in a `minipage` with `\centering` inside it.  This will allow long wrapped titles to wrap properly: (Thanks to egreg for making the centring code better.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\section}
    [block]{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\rlap{\thesection}}{0em}
    {\hspace*{.05\textwidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{.9\textwidth}\centering}[\end{minipage}]

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A very long section title to show that it will wrap correctly}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]