# How can I change the width of the subsection headings to 4 in?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

I am using `\@startsection` in `pdflatex` to define the formatting of the subsection headings.  I would like their width to be limited to `4in`, and centered.  I can change the third item `{\z@}` to indent the left hand side, but it doesn't center.  Is there another way of doing this?

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}
   {\@startsection
      {subsection}
       {2}%
       {\z@}%
       {\li}%
       {1pt}%
       {\reset@font\centering\normalsize}}
```

Comment: have a look at [format-title-section-number-flush-left-and-title-centered/49320#49320](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49314/format-title-section-number-flush-left-and-title-centered/49320#49320); it's not exactly the same, but it's pretty close

Comment: What about the subsection number?

Answer (score 5):

Using the titlesec package you can do this as follows, by first calculating the necessary margins:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength{\mymargin}
\setlength{\mymargin}{0.5\textwidth}
\addtolength{\mymargin}{-2in}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fillast}{\thesubsection}{1ex
minus .1ex}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\mymargin}{*3.25}{*1.5}[\mymargin]
```

[image: Sample output]

This uses the default `hang` style with the label hanging to the left of the title.  Use `\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{...}` to move the label in, so the first line as a whole is centered, or `[display]` to have the label on the line above.